# Library conflict with OpenSSL and PHP 5.3.3?

Tags: php, soap, openssl

I am trying to implement a PHP SOAP based web service into my web application. I am getting a series of errors which seem to point to a conflict of libraries with regard to OpenSSL (or Curl, etc.), this I have understood by searching the internet for similar errors, but thought a general consensus that libraries are the issue, there is no solution that I can find.

```
Warning (2): SoapClient::__doRequest() [soapclient.--dorequest]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:140773F2:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert unexpected message [CORE/vendors/Startrack/WSSecurity.php, line 110]
Warning (2): SoapClient::__doRequest() [soapclient.--dorequest]: Failed to enable crypto [CORE/vendors/Startrack/WSSecurity.php, line 110]
Warning (2): SoapClient::__doRequest() [soapclient.--dorequest]: connect() failed: Unspecified error [CORE/vendors/Startrack/WSSecurity.php, line 110]
Notice (8): Undefined property: SoapFault::$detail [APP/controllers/startrack_controller.php, line 38]
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/controllers/startrack_controller.php, line 38]

Could not connect to host
```

This is being served from a Mac OSX Lion server. PHP 5.3.3 is installed, and the extensions for OpenSSL, Curl and SOAP are enabled. This is being built within CakePHP which explains the syntax of the error messages above. I am using a PHP Web Service bundle already provided. The above works when hosted via MAMP, but I am hoping to not have to rely on MAMP.

The only incompatibility I can find is between the OpenSSL headers and library versions, but from what I know this ought not be a problem?

```
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
```

I am trying to understand if the assumed 'conflict' is between my server and the remote server? The WSDL file is included in the Web Service API, as they hope to avoid any issues, and it works through a MAMP install on the same computer. So I think it is a setup issue between Apache/PHP and Curl/OpenSSL.

Any pointers to how to establish the actual issue, and rectify it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you are trying to connect with an SSL 3 enabled server, that may (?) have SSL 2 disabled.

Try connecting to the server like this on the command line:

```
 openssl s_client -connect {SERVER NAME OR IP}:443 -state
```

If that does not work, then try connecting like this:

```
 openssl s_client -ssl3 -connect {SERVER NAME OR IP}:443 -state
```

If that does work, then try creating a wrapper class, similar to [this one found in the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php#97029).

You should add a line similar to:

```
 curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

inside the `callCurl` function to force SOAP to connect over version three of ssl.